# How to use older object library versions in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ms-office

I have Office 365, but no one else on in my department will get it until the end of the year. I made a few macros for us to use in excel VBA, but ever since my upgrade any macro I touch upgrades all object libraries to version 16.0. My coworkers are still on 15.0 from the previous version of office.

I've tried late binding, which lets me avoid using any of the program specific object libraries. However, I cannot get remove the reference 'Microsoft Office Object Library 16.0' and it's preventing all of my coworkers from using and macros I create or save.

Is there a way to force my excel vba to use 15.0 libraries?

Comment: The issue is the 'Microsoft Excel Object Library 16.0' cannot be disabled at all. It says "Cannot disable reference - in use" even in a blank empty workbook. I disabled every reference I could and make a simple 2 line macro. Works fine on 365, but when I sent it to someone on 2013 they could not run it because "Missing reference library."

Comment: Yes, see "Microsoft **Excel** Object Library 16.0" is rather different than "Microsoft **Office** Object Library 16.0" - if the problem is the host library (no you can't remove it), then there shouldn't be any problems, as long as you're not using types and members that don't exist in the earlier versions. People build VBA stuff in Excel 2019 that runs in Excel 2010 all the time, 16.0 vs 15.0 isn't the problem. Unless 365 broke that, of course. Then again, the only real solution is to develop on the lowest common version that's in use.

Comment: «ever since my upgrade any macro I touch upgrades all object libraries to version 16.0. My coworkers are still on 15.0 from the previous version of office.» The simple solution is to make your changes on a PC using the earliest of Office you need to support.